# How to make command line tool “ctpu” be recognized by my terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, unix

I downloaded the `ctpu` command-line tool made by Google. This tool makes it easy to set up and run Cloud TPUs for deep learning projects. I successfully downloaded the tool to my `~` directory (`Users/NameOfUserAccount`), and my macOS computer said that the filetype of the `ctpu` tool was a "Unix executable". I tried to see if my terminal would recognize the command-line tool. Apparently, it didn't because I typed `ctpu up`, but the terminal didn't recognize the command, and the `ctpu` tool wouldn't autocomplete (pressing tab wouldn't autocomplete `ctpu`). The only way I could run the `ctpu` tool was by typing `~/ctpu`. In order to fix this, I tried adding the following line to my `~/.bash_profile`:

`export PATH="/Users/NameOfUserAccount/ctpu/bin:$PATH"`

Realizing that the downloaded `ctpu` tool was not a directory but rather a Unix executable, I tried putting the tool in a `bin` folder and changing the line to:

`export PATH="/Users/NameOfUserAccount/bin/ctpu:$PATH"`

And yet, the terminal still didn't recognize the `ctpu` tool.

How can I make it so that I no longer have to manually enter the file path to the `ctpu` tool and can have the terminal permanently recognize the command-line tool? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

$PATH takes directories, not files:

```
export PATH="/Users/NameOfUserAccount/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```